# Getting error while trying to fill data in website after login

Tags: vba, using, extract

I am trying to prepare a macro to pull data from UHC web after login that website and then auto fill the eligibility form, but it shows an error while filling data after login into web.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub UHCdata()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://provider-linkhealth.unitedhealthcareonline.com/b2c/LoginAction.do?islink=true"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
Call ie.document.getElementById("EMAIL").setAttribute("value", "Arun14")
Call ie.document.getElementById("PASSWORD").setAttribute("value", "Borgess147")
Set AllInputs = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each hyper_link In AllInputs
If hyper_link.Name = "submitButton" Then
hyper_link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 3
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
ie.navigate "https://provider-linkhealth.unitedhealthcareonline.com/b2c/LoginAction.do?islink=true&_alpsPartnerName=tru"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
Call ie.document.getElementByName("enrolleeNo").setAttribute("value", "1114521")
End Sub
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: It shows Run time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I.N.D.E.N.T.A.T.I.O.N.

Answer (score 0):

Your original error, I believe, is caused by

```
ie.document.getElementByName("enrolleeNo").setAttribute("value", "1114521")
```

The correct method is `getElementsByName()`. Notice the `"s"` which indicates a collection is returned. You would access the appropriate element in the collection by index e.g.

```
ie.document.getElementsByName("enrolleeNo")(0).setAttribute("value", "1114521")
```

The website has changed. The code below show you how to achieve all the initial login parts. As the login is not valid, I cannot attest to the very final part, but it is correct syntactically.

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UHCdata()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://provider-linkhealth.unitedhealthcareonline.com/b2c/LoginAction.do?islink=true"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.getElementById("userNameId_input").Value = "Arun14"
        .document.getElementById("passwdId_input").Value = "Borgess147"
        .document.querySelector("#SignIn").Click
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .navigate "https://provider-linkhealth.unitedhealthcareonline.com/b2c/LoginAction.do?islink=true&_alpsPartnerName=tru"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        'ie.document.getElementByName("enrolleeNo").setAttribute("value", "1114521") '<== This returns a collection. Which to fill?
        .document.getElementsByName("enrolleeNo")(0).Value = "1114521"

        Stop '<==  Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```